# Asp.Net Core - Return values from the controller and put the values ​into the inputs by Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-core

I have a drop down list and I want the value to be sent to the controller when an option is selected,replaceing the returned values ​​in the desired inputs

Html Inputs :

```
<input type="text" class="form-control js-inputs" id="microchipcode">
<input class="form-control js-inputs" id="fa-horse">
<input type="text" id="fa-fatherhorse" class="form-control js-inputs">
```

Html DropDown:

```
$('.js-selected-item').change(function () {               
let Value = $(this).val();
$.ajax({
    data: { value: Value },
    Url: "/Horse/GetHorseByMcode",
    type: "post",
    success: function (data) {
    }
});
```

});

Controller :

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetInfoHorse(string value)
    {
        var horse = await _coach.GetHorseByMcode(value);
        if (horse != null)
        {
            return Json(horse);
        }

        return NotFound();
    }
```

Query :

```
public async Task<Horse> GetHorseByMcode(string value)
    {
        return await _context.Horses.SingleAsync(h => h.MicrochipCode == value.Trim());
    }
```

Comment: So what's the problem? There's no real question here? Is it working? Is it not working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: @JamesS I do not know how to insert values in inputs

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put a value into an `input` via js, add an ID to the inputs and do the following:

JS:

```
document.getElementById('//inputId').value = '';
```

Jquery:

```
("#//inputId").val("");
```

Comment: An object returns and inside this object are values ​​that I want to put inside several inputs

Comment: @sunboy_sunboy Well access the values in the object returned and put them in the inputs such as `data.//whatever`

Comment: How do I access the data inside the object?

Comment: @sunboy_sunboy I've just said above. The object passed back to the `success` (`data` here) and then whatever the variable (starting in lower case) in the object. For example `data.horseName` or whatever is in the `horse` class

Comment: thank, How to replace Drop Down list ?

Answer (score 0):

> How do I access the data inside the object?

You can check the request and response in f12 developer tool Network tab, like below.

[image]

and implement frontend code to populate input field(s) in ajax `success` callback function based on your actual returned data.

*For example:*

```
success: function (data) {
    $("#fa-fatherhorse").val(data.fatherHorse);
    //populate other inputs based on your actual returned data
```

> How to replace Drop Down list ?

If you want to dynamically set the selected value/option of the dropdown, you can try:

```
$("#dropdown_id_here").val(value_of_selected_option);
```

If you want to dynamically append `<option>` to your dropdown, you can try:

```
var newoption = "<option value='" + option_val + "'>" + option_text + "</option>";

$("#dropdown_id_here").append(newoption);
```